# Not able to install cypress from Node package using npm i cypress -g

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, cypress

When I am trying to install Cypress from NPM I am getting below error. I have Used the correct proxy also but the issue still remains the same.

C:\Users\mXXXXX\Work\Toolss\Test>npm i cypress -g
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\mXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\cypress -> C:\Users\mXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress

> cypress@5.3.0 postinstall C:\Users\mXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cypress
> node index.js --exec install

Installing Cypress (version: 5.3.0)

×  Downloading Cypress
→ Cypress Version: 5.3.0
Unzipping Cypress
Finishing Installation
The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration

Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

---

URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/5.3.0?platform=win32&arch=x64
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

---

Platform: win32 (10.0.17134)
Cypress Version: 5.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@5.3.0 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@5.3.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-09-29T14_52_51_373Z-debug.log

Thanks in advance.